# variable timer with setTimeout() inside jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout

I want to cycle through a bunch of jpg pictures as a slideshow.  I have been using setInterval with success so far. However, I now want to have each slide show for a custom time.  For example slide 1 shows for 6 seconds, then slide 2 for 3 seconds, etc.  I tried the following code:

```
var sl = [["PodLoop1.jpg", 6000], ["PodLoop2.jpg", 3000]];
$.each(sl, function(i, value) {
    fl = '<img src="media/' + value[0] + '" height="100%">'
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#InnerMedia").html(fl);
        if (i >= sl.length) {
            window.location.href = "./media.php"; // refresh to restart from the beginning
        }
    }, value[1])
});
```

But this doesn't work.  It just jumps to the last slide in the list. What am I doing wrong?  I have looked at several similar questions on SO, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797421/issues-with-settimeout-inside-jquery-each), but none of them seem to deal with a variable timer.

Answer (score 1):

***i*** will never be equal **sl.length**
change the code to `i >= sl.length-1`

Comment: Good point. I missed it. +1 :-) But this is a partial answer as user wishes to chain events.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are using `.each` loop.

#### setTimeout

What setTimeout does is it registers an event at designated time. Now when you run this in loop, this will register 2 events, 1 at *after 3secs* and another at *after 6secs*. So it runs correctly.

To fix this, you will have to chain initialisation of these `setTimeout`s. You will have to register new event inside another one.

**Sample**

```js
function createTimeout(arr, index){
  if(!arr[index] == undefined) return;
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(arr[index][0]);
    createTimeout(arr, ++index)
  }, arr[index][1])
}

var sl = [["PodLoop1.jpg", 6000], ["PodLoop2.jpg", 3000]];
createTimeout(sl, 0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't recursion be a problem when I have a longer list?

Comment: `if(!arr[index] == undefined) return;` will make sure it does not go in endless loop

Comment: I was referring to the state where I have a 100 files (say) the memory usage will be huge! Because recursion...

Comment: @Chiwda No. You are passing reference and index to function. So it will not have that huge impact.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7023678/989468) especially the discussion on memory towards the end.

Comment: @Chiwda If you notice, we are passing reference of array and mentioned answer is creating `bigArray` inside function call. So in our case, closure will not be created as values are passed as arguments. So this, in my understanding, will not create memory issues.